# Get localized name other channel

Tags: firefox-addon

I get the version number of the firefox from the applications.ini.

Then I hardcoded that between date #### and #### v35 is release. So now based on this and the current date and version from applications.ini I figure out the channel of other builds.

But now I want to get the localized name of the channel.

So for example I'm using beta channel and from this build I want to get the localized name of "Nightly" in chineese, so it has the chineese characters, and word for nightly in chineese. Can this also be obtained from the `applications.ini`? Is `[App] -> Name` localized in applications.ini?

This is the applications.ini method: https://ask.mozilla.org/question/705/detect-if-auroranightlybetanormal-and-get-paths/ (credits to @paa)

### EDIT

i discovered this file: `OS.Path.join(Services.dirsvc.get('XREExeF', Ci.nsIFile).parent.path, 'defaults', 'pref', 'channel-prefs.js')`

its contents is the following:

```
//@line 2 "c:\builds\moz2_slave\rel-m-beta-w32_bld-00000000000\build\browser\app\profile\channel-prefs.js"
/* This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
 * License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
 * file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/. */

pref("app.update.channel", "beta");
```

Is this a reliable check? Does this `channel-prefs.js` file exist for all builds as soon as they are installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a reliable check?

Not really. There used to be channel switcher add-ons, and in theory the user can change this pref (although at the moment this is not sufficient to really switch the channel I think).

> Does this channel-prefs.js file exist for all builds as soon as they are installed?

Yes, for now. But this is an implementation detail. There is no guarantee that the file won't be moved or renamed later, or merged with another file.

> Can this also be obtained from the applications.ini?

The localized name? I didn't even know there was one... I thought it was called e.g. "Nightly" in all locales like it was a (product) name. But yeah, it is theoretically possible to localize that string. It is not available from the ini file, though.

I wouldn't poke in application.ini anyway, and instead just use `Services.appinfo.defaultUpdateChannel`

> But now I want to get the localized name of the channel.

Since you're in a running Firefox instance already (judging from your `OS.File` code), you should use the string bundle service to load `chrome://branding/locale/brand.properties` and get the `brandShortName` or `brandFullName` string from there.

Comment: Thanks @namaier, do you know since what FF version, the `channel-pref.js` file would get put there? Thanks for the brand.properties, is there any way from one build, to get the brandShortName for other channels, like from aurora channel to get the nightly/release/beta brandShortName? The biggest thing I'm trying to do is detect channel of another build based on it's build path which I have stored.